# Mocking an api call in Jest with React Typescript

Tags: axios, react-testing-library, ts-jest, react-typescript, jest-mock-axios

I'm following some documentation on mocking an api call with Jest, although trying to do it with react.tsx.
I've looked at a lot of different stack Q&As and elsewhere online and am not understanding what I am missing from my test file to make my test pass.
So far I'm exporting my fetchWeatherData function from my WeatherMocks.tsx:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
    
export const fetchWeatherData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('http://mock-api-call/weather/get-weather');
  return response.data.result.weather.forcast;
};
```

and importing to my test file where I am trying to use this function to mock the data.
`Weather.test.tsx`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchWeatherData } from '../../__mocks__/WeatherMocks';
    
jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;
    
describe('mock api calls', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
    
  test('return forcast Sunny', async () => {
    mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({
       data: {
         result: {
           weather: {
            forcast: 'Sunny',
            max: 28,
            min: 17,
            description: 'Clear skys all day with a warm summber breaze ariving in the afternoon',
          },
        },
      },
    });

    const forecast = await fetchWeatherData();
    expect(forecast.forcast).toEqual('Sunny');
  });
});
```

If someone can help me get past this hurdle I would greatly appreciate it as I was told this is a really simple method.

The new testing error

```bash
 expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
    
    Expected: "Sunny"
    Received: undefined
    
      24 |     });
      25 |     const forecast = await fetchWeatherData();
    > 26 |     expect(forecast.forcast).toEqual('Sunny');
         |                              ^
      27 |   });
      28 | });
      29 |
```

Comment: What do you think the value of `response.data` is?

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
result:
weather:
description: "Clear skys all day with a warm summber breaze ariving in the afternoon"
forcast: "Sunny"
max: 28
min: 17

Comment: And have you tried to validate that assumption? Because I don't think it's reflected in your test double.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes although I'm still receiving undefined instead of 'Sunny'

Comment: The test double now looks correct, but either your expectation or the implementation is wrong - `fetchWeatherData` does **not** return an object with a `forcast` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Second answer

It is failing because in your method you are already returning the weather:

```js
  // ...
  const forecast = await fetchWeatherData();
  const expect(forecast).toEqual('Sunny');
  // ...
```

---

#### Previous answer

What you are doing is already correct, however you are not creating the object structure which you are later accessing:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchWeatherData } from '../../__mocks__/WeatherMocks';

jest.mock('axios');
const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>;

describe('mock api calls', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  test('return forcast Sunny', async () => {
    mockedAxios.get.mockResolvedValue({
      // You need to mock all the structure:
      // response -> data -> result -> weather -> forcast
      // You have only:
      // response -> data
      data: {
        result: {
          weather: {
            // Are you sure its forcast and not forecast??
            forcast: 'Sunny',
            max: 28,
            min: 17,
            description: 'Clear skys all day with a warm summber breaze ariving in the afternoon',
          },
        },
      },
    });

    const forecast = await fetchWeatherData();
    expect(forecast).toEqual('Sunny');
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I had removed that code. In doing it I have created a new error now though the test is receiving undefined instead of 'Sunny'